# Is it possible to register a generic list service in Autofac XML configuration?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I am trying to configure dependencies both programatically and through XML. I have a list of services of type `IMyService`. I have registered each service to the container builder programatically:

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.Register(t => new Logger()).As<ILogger>();

builder.Register(t => new MyService1(t.Resolve<ILogger>()));
builder.Register(t => new MyService2(t.Resolve<ILogger>()));
builder.Register(t => new MyService3(t.Resolve<ILogger>()));
builder.Register(t => new MyService4(t.Resolve<ILogger>()));
builder.Register(t => new MyService5(t.Resolve<ILogger>()));
```

What I would now like to do, is to register a dynamic list of these services through XML so that I can inject only the required services among these to my Engine (the services required can change based on deployment environments).

I can do this programatically as:

```
builder.Register(t => new List<IMyService> { 
                          t.Resolve<MyService1>(), 
                          t.Resolve<MyService2>(), 
                          t.Resolve<MyService3>() })
       .Named<IList<IMyService>>("ListOfMyServices");
```

But to avoid code re-compilation plus deployment every time the required services change, I am trying to do this through Autofac XML configuration? Is there a way to do this?

My engine registry, which need not be XML configured, is this:

```
builder.Register(t => new MyEngine(t.ResolveNamed<IList<IMyService>>("ListOfMyServices")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Autofac* XML configuration is really simple and this scenario is not built-in supported by *Autofac* XML configuration.

One way to do would be to use named registration and specify the list of requested service in the AppSettings configuration file

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Logger>().As<ILogger>();

builder.RegisterType<MyService1>().As<IMyService>().Named<IMyService>("Service1");
builder.RegisterType<MyService2>().As<IMyService>().Named<IMyService>("Service2");
builder.RegisterType<MyService3>().As<IMyService>().Named<IMyService>("Service3");
builder.RegisterType<MyService4>().As<IMyService>().Named<IMyService>("Service4");
builder.RegisterType<MyService5>().As<IMyService>().Named<IMyService>("Service5");
```

Then you can register `MyEngine` like this

```
String[] namedServices = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyServices"].Split(','); 

builder.Register(c => {
           var services = namedServices.Select(s => c.ResolveNamed<IMyService>(s));
           return new MyEngine(services.ToList());
       })
       .As<IMyEngine>();
```

And in your config file :

```xml
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MyServices" value="Service1,Service2,Service5" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yeah, it can be done by this way and I had thought of it. But I actually wanted to know if it can be done through Autofac XML configuration. Marking this as answer as you pointed that it cant be done.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot paste the code from the phone.
But steps are the following:
1. Register all your services in XML config. But only services you really intent to use with your  configuration. 
2. Assign names to each services.
3. Create app.config value where you store all required services.
4. Read this section on start and inject this onto list of services.